# Deciding what to return - bool value

Tags: c++, boolean

So I am almost done with this, I cant figure out what I need to return in my overloaded output operator. Originally it was down as return less, but I keep getting the error (a reference of type "std::ostream&" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "bool") what excatly do I need to out in my return statement?

```
class Student
{
 private:
    int stuID;
    int year;
    double gpa;
 public:
    Student(const int, const int, const double);
    void showYear();
    bool operator<(const Student);
 friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Student&);
};
Student::Student(const int i, int y, const double g)
{
   stuID = i;
   year = y;
   gpa = g;
}
void Student::showYear()
{
   cout << year;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Student& otherStu)
{
   bool less = false;
   if (otherStu.year < otherStu.year)
     less = true;
     return ;
}
int main()
{
    Student a(111, 2, 3.50), b(222, 1, 3.00);
    if(a < b)
   {
      a.showYear();
      cout << " is less than ";
      b.showYear();
   }
   else
   {
     a.showYear();
     cout << " is not less than ";
     b.showYear();
   }
  cout << endl;
  _getch()
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: By convention, `operator<<` should return the first parameter directly.

Comment: and in fact thats what you have said you are returning, so return it (you gonna have to name it)

Comment: It seems you may have confused `operator<<` with `operator<`.

Comment: `if (otherStu.year < otherStu.year)` is always `false`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are confused between `operator<` and `operator<<`.

```
// operator< function to compare two objects.
// Make it a const member function
bool Student::operator<(const Student& other) const
{
   return (this->year < other.year);
}

// operator<< function to output data of one object to a stream.
// Output the data of a Student
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Student& stu)
{
   return (out << stu.stuID << " " << stu.year << " " << stu.gpa);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

You need to return the ostream you have in the parameter..

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Student& obj)
{

    return os << obj.stuID << ", " << obj.year << ", " << obj.gpa;
}
```